# Mojave suddenly restarts after running VMware Horizon Client for a few minutes

Tags: mojave, reboot

I am currently on macOS Mojave.

After the system boots up, I use VMware Horizon Client for Mac application to connect to a virtual Desktop (VD) for work. After using VMware Horizon Client for a few minutes, macOS restarts suddenly.

This does not always happen, only 6 out of 10 times. After restarting, macOS shows a message saying "Your computer was restarted because of a problem":
[image]

The following information was shown when I clicked "Report..." in the above dialog box

> *** Panic Report *** panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff800f5304b4): assertion failed: ifp->if_sndbyte_total >= len, file:
> /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-4903.271.2/bsd/netinet/in_pcb.c,
> line: 3794 Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address
> 0xffffff81233e3a10 : 0xffffff800efae6ed  0xffffff81233e3a60 :
> 0xffffff800f0ea185  0xffffff81233e3aa0 : 0xffffff800f0db8ba
> 0xffffff81233e3b10 : 0xffffff800ef5bb40  0xffffff81233e3b30 :
> 0xffffff800efae107  0xffffff81233e3c50 : 0xffffff800efadf53
> 0xffffff81233e3cc0 : 0xffffff800f5304b4  0xffffff81233e3cf0 :
> 0xffffff800f52ff3c  0xffffff81233e3d40 : 0xffffff800f52f8a8
> 0xffffff81233e3d80 : 0xffffff800f51fc91  0xffffff81233e3db0 :
> 0xffffff800f522c10  0xffffff81233e3e00 : 0xffffff800f522fbb
> 0xffffff81233e3e20 : 0xffffff800f498383  0xffffff81233e3e90 :
> 0xffffff800f49800d  0xffffff81233e3f00 : 0xffffff800f49cb24
> 0xffffff81233e3f40 : 0xffffff800f5ba5ed  0xffffff81233e3fa0 :
> 0xffffff800ef5c306
>
> BSD process name corresponding to current thread: Google Chrome He
>
> Mac OS version: 18G103

How do I resolve this error? I am stuck thinking if upgrading to a newer version of macOS will solve this issue.

Comment: Use the `code` markdown for panic logs etc, ctrl/k rather than ctrl/q to quote it. It's really hard to fix after the fact, so it's better if you can re-paste.

Comment: Welcome to [apple.se]! And while you're at it: `VMware Horizon client` should *not* be formatted like that: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135112/295232

Comment: According to the official documentation (https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Horizon-Client-for-Mac/2111/horizon-client-mac-installation/GUID-48210A98-6377-4486-BBE2-99AAD4912714.html#GUID-48210A98-6377-4486-BBE2-99AAD4912714), VMware Horizon Client for Mac supports macOS Catalina or later, so you seem to be running an unsupported configuration. Apart from that, macOS Mojave is no longer supported (following the rule of thumb that Apple supports the previous two iterations of the current version), so I'd definitely recommend that you upgrade to Big Sur, Catalina or Monterey, if possible.

Comment: @jaume Thanks for link. I shall upgrade my mac.

Comment: @Nitz Thank you for getting back to me. I've posted my comment as an answer, you may want to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I resolve this error? I am stuck thinking if upgrading to a newer version of macOS will solve this issue.

According to the [official documentation](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Horizon-Client-for-Mac/2111/horizon-client-mac-installation/GUID-48210A98-6377-4486-BBE2-99AAD4912714.html#GUID-48210A98-6377-4486-BBE2-99AAD4912714), VMware Horizon Client for Mac supports macOS Catalina or later, so you seem to be running an unsupported configuration.

Apart from that, macOS Mojave is no longer supported (following the rule of thumb that Apple supports the previous two iterations of the current version), so I'd definitely recommend that you upgrade to Catalina or Monterey, if possible.